# How to create a counter?

Tags: javascript, php, counter, html

I would like to create a "Count me in!" button on my site, but i don't know much about PHP and JavaScript yet. So I am asking for your help: The button should increase a number on the site and the same user should not be able to click it multiple times, but if it possible I would like to solve this problem without registration. It would only be a button which increases a number on the site.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. We are not here to develop for you, but to help you debug your app. You have to try and develop something. If you don't know anything about web programming, there are zillions of free tutorials out there, please go have a look.

Comment: See tutorials like http://www.w3schools.com/. It would be a great help.

Comment: bind your button call with the ip or set session on page open, try this it will help

Comment: I am sorry. I will try my best, and look at some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can create a counter. But for real time implementation, you need to look at more features such as security and database management.

**add_count.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["add_count"]))
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE["add_count"]))
    {
        echo "exist";
    }
    else
    {
        //Change your counts in database or how ever you may want.
        setcookie("add_count",1);
        echo "success";
    }
}
else{echo "fail";}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html><body></body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#counter").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"add_count.php";
            data:{"add_count":1},
            type:"post",
            success:function(response){
                if(response=="success"){alert("Your click has been saved!");}
                else if(response=="exist"){alert("You have already clicked!");}
                else{alert("Unknown Error! Please Try Again!");}
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```